# How do I control style of material-ui SelectField

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui with react `"material-ui": "^0.19.2"` and am trying to place a `SelectField` in a table. This much is working fine but the margin and/or padding applied to the select component is doing 2 unwanted things. First is the table rows now adjust to the height of the select which is making the size of the entire row too high. Secondly the alignment of everything else in the row is off.

My code:

```
<SelectField
    value={ props.value }
    hintText="Select location.."
    style={ {
        width: 150,
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0
    } }
    onChange={ (event, key, payload) => this.updateLocation(event, payload, props.index, props.original.something) }>
        { ::this.createMenu() }
</SelectField>

createMenu = () => {
    const { locations } = this.props.list;
    return locations.map((location, i) => {
        return <MenuItem key={ i } value={ location } primaryText={ location } />
    });
}
```

If I could control the styling around the component(`Textfield`??) that is rendered I would try and make it fit properly but the style prop on the `SelectField` only seems to style the dropdown list.

Another option for me here could be to go with a popover for the field and render a custom component to attach it to - but I haven't had much luck when trying use that.

Comment: Please add your code as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: Done - sorry about that

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `style` prop of `<SelectField>`? You can find the component's API [here](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.19.2/#/components/select-field).

Comment: Isn’t that what the style prop is doing above?

Comment: But you are only setting the width there, when you seem to have a problem with the height.

Comment: I have added code to show how I can get it to look OK - but there has to be a better way I would assume!

Answer (score 2):

The following props on the `SelectField` give me what I want:

```
   <SelectField
          value={props.value}
          hintText="Select location.."
          style={{
            width: 150,
            height: 15,
            lineHeight: 15,
            position: 'relative',
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: '0.9em'
          }}
          menuStyle={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -12.5,
          }}
          underlineStyle={{
            position: 'relative',
            top: 20,
          }}
          onChange={(event, key, payload)=>this.updateLocation(event,payload,props.index,props.original.something)}
        >
          {
            ::this.createMenu()
          }
        </SelectField>
```

if anyone knows a better way please add an answer but for now this will answer my question.

Comment: Where do you referencing this from? I looking for a way to add styling to selected menu item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<b>Just add maxHeight={200} inside SelectField</b>

< SelectField
multiple

fullWidth = {true}

value={this.state.candidate_profile_arr}

onChange = {this.handleChange}

maxHeight = {200}

>

{this.state.profile.map((profile, i) =>

<MenuItem  value={profile.id} key={i} primaryText={profile.name} />)
}

</SelectField>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please not that code only answers are not recommended. Consider adding a bit of context to explain which part of the code addresses the problem the OP had.